# Wordpress plugins not deployed to Google App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have installed a couple of Wordpress plugins on my local development server. When I deploy to the cloud, however, my plugins are not available.

I understand that the read-only file system prevents updating plugins from the deployed app as per [this blog post](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2014/01/15/php-app-engine-apps-and-file-system-concepts/#more-361), but is there a trick to getting locally installed plugins to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

When you install the plugins on your local server, it should work when you deploy. No need for a trick.

Make sure you install the plugins to the plugins directory in your wordpress project which you deploy, and make sure you enable the plugins on the **production server**